# can someone assist with experiance of the domainbox api and php please

Tags: php, api

Has anyone had experience with the domainbox.com api? I have never done anything like this before and any help would be really appreciated. What i'm trying to do is using php send the request and bring back the results displaying them on the page but to be honest i don't even know where to start or if this is even the best way to do it.

html

```
<form action="searchdomain.php" method="post">
domain: <input type="text" name="domainname">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

php

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient('https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL', array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));


// populate the inputs....
    $params = array(
       'AuthenticationParameters' => array(
          'Reseller' => 'pulseinternet',
          'Username' => 'roy_admin',
          'Password' => '*********'
        ),
        'CommandParameters' => array(
            'DomainName' => '($_POST["domainname"])',
            'LaunchPhase' => 'GA'
        )
    );

$result = $client->CheckDomainAvailability($params, AvailabilityStatus);

print_r($result);
?>
```

results

```
stdClass Object ( [CheckDomainAvailabilityResult] => stdClass Object ( [ResultCode] => 250 [ResultMsg] => TLD '' not supported [TxID] => d015865c-b99e-400f-94b9-badf89b0216f [AvailabilityStatus] => 3 [AvailabilityStatusDescr] => ErrorOccurred [LaunchPhase] => GA [DropDate] => [BackOrderAvailable] => [AdditionalResults] => stdClass Object ( ) ) )
```

Thanks in advance Roy

Comment: Have you logged in and viewed the "complete documentation with example code"? I suggest that you make an attempt, then let us know what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: hi showdev thanks for getting back, I have been looking at it for 2 days i get what info its going to give back my problem is i dont know how to send from a search box to it and display the info back on the page.

Comment: I don't doubt that it's confusing. I'm pretty sure you'll get some help if you just make some sort of attempt. Show something you've tried and let us know where you got stuck. Coder Power!

Comment: But what does(n't) it do? What is your actual question?

Comment: is this how you would do this? its must not be sending the domain name as in the results it says [ResultMsg] => TLD '' not supported

Comment: what I can't do now is take just one piece of the results and have it on the page

Comment: here you are a working example

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a working example:

```
$dom = 'test12309go.com';
$tld = '.com,.net,.org';
//$client = new SoapClient('https://sandbox.domainbox.net/?WSDL', array('trace' => true, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$client = new SoapClient('https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL', array('trace' => true, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$params = array(
    'AuthenticationParameters' => array(
        'Reseller' => 'MyReseller',
        'Username' => 'MyUsername',
        'Password' => 'MyPassword'
    ),
    'CommandParameters' => array(
        'DomainName' => $dom,
    'TLDs' => $tld,
    'Limit' => '10',
    'CheckAtRegistry' => true,
      'DomainCheck' => array(
        'Include' => true
      ),
      'NameSuggestions' => array(
        'Include' => false
      ),
      'PremiumDomains' => array(
        'Include' => false
      ),
  )
);
$result = $client->CheckDomainAvailabilityPlus($params);
//echo $client->__getLastRequest();
print_r($result);
```